# How can I partially match these 2 strings in javascript

Tags: javascript

So to make this easier Ill provide contents of certain variables.

```
{{element url}} contains the string I want to compare (which is also an url)
{{url}} Only contains my current url path
{{ArrayObject}} contains a set similar to below
```

.

```
function() {
var data= [
{ url:     "ReplaceThis",
elementUrl:     "ReplaceThis",
category:     "ReplaceThis",
action:     "ReplaceThis",
label:  "ReplaceThis",
value : "ReplaceThis"
  }
];
    return data;
}
```

The code I am having trouble with for example is this one.

```
function() {
try{
  var elementurl = "{{element url}}";
  var url = "{{url}}";
  var arrObj = {{ArrayObject}};
  var check = false;
  var ctr;
  for (i = 0; i < arrObj .length; i++) { 
    if (elementurl.lastIndexOf(arrObj[i].elementUrl,0)===0 &&    url.lastIndexOf(arrObj[i].url, 0)===0) {
    check = true;
    ctr=i;
}        
  }
if (check == true){
return arrObj[ctr].action;
}else{

return {{event}};
}
}catch(err) {
    return ; err.message;
}
}
```

As you can see the line that contains if

```
(elementurl.lastIndexOf(arrObj[i].elementUrl,0)===0 &&
```

I tried to replace with this

```
if (elementurl.IndexOf(arrObj[i].elementUrl) != -1 &&    url.lastIndexOf(arrObj[i].url, 0)===0) {
```

I've tried several things and essentially what I want to do is arrObj[i].elementUrl will contain a partial elementurl

For example elementUrl may contain oogle.com but  elementurl contains google.com how can i tweak my link to support this or something like oogl would match google.com as well for example.

Thoughts?

Comment: `var arrObj = {{ArrayObject}};` .. does that even compile?!

Comment: hard to make much sense out of this with all the `{{}}` braces in it. Are you mixing template language syntax with javascript here?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I don't understand your question but if you are trying to match strings based on patterns you can use regular expressions.

```
var url1 = 'http://www.google.com/something',
    url2 = 'google.com';

if ((new RegExp(url2)).test(url1)){
    // google.com exists in http://www.google.com/something
}

if ((new RegExp(url1)).test(url2)){
    // this wont happen, http://www.google.com/something is no a part of google.com
}
```

Regexes are really powerfull, you can do a google search for plenty of tutorials on this subject.

Comment: Unfortunately, it will also say that "google.com" exists in "googleacom"

Comment: Could you let other users know why the dot behaves that way in regexs now that you mention it?

Comment: I might as well inquire why you're not simply using `String.indexOf()`, which would circumvent this issue altogether.

Comment: Do you understand what the issue is exactly? From what I understand the user needs to match string patterns and regex would be a very good approach, switching to indexOf if no wildcards are needed in the pattern. But regex can give the asker another perspective with which to tackle the issue. For users wondering why 'google.com' also matches 'googleacom' its because the .(dot) in regexes matches any character, if you need to match a dot exactly you need to escape it like so \.

Comment: I have no clue what the question is about (which is why I've voted to close it), so my only context is your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Jack's idea seems to have worked the best. I can partial match nicely using indexof like he suggested. The exact change I made was

```
if (elementurl.lastIndexOf(arrObj[i].elementUrl,0)===0 &&    url.lastIndexOf(arrObj[i].url, 0)===0) {
```

to

```
if (elementurl.indexOf(arrObj[i].elementUrl) > -1 &&    url.lastIndexOf(arrObj[i].url, 0)===0) {
```

thanks you for all the replies.